# Postgresql 9.6 initdb fails in Centos 7 docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos7

I am trying to setup a docker image with Centos7 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

I use the centos:centos7 image as base, and I follow the steps from this page: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation

The step to initialize the DB

```
sh-4.2# /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
failed to find PGDATA setting in postgresql-9.6.service
```

I tried to follow these steps to enable systemd for the CentOS image, 
https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/
But it does not help.

I also tried to comment out the stmts in the postgresql96-setup script

```
#PGDATA=`systemctl show -p Environment "${SERVICE_NAME}.service" |
#                sed 's/^Environment=//' | tr ' ' '\n' |
#                sed -n 's/^PGDATA=//p' | tail -n 1`
#if [ x"$PGDATA" = x ]; then
#    echo "failed to find PGDATA setting in ${SERVICE_NAME}.service"
#    exit 1
#fi
```

Now the initdb works. But starting the service gives me the same error message

```
sh-4.2# systemctl enable postgresql-9.6.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/postgresql-9.6.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.6.service.
sh-4.2#  systemctl start postgresql-9.6.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Did I miss anything? Anyone can help me out of this?

Comment: Can't you use the official postgres image https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: @Rao I've got the same problem.  The one you link to is not Centos7. The CentOS 7 version doesn't have a "latest". The one they link to is 9.5, not 9.6, and isn't set up as root for futher installs: https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/postgresql-95-centos7/

Comment: This seems likely to be a route to a solution for the `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`: https://serverfault.com/questions/824975/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 1):

The "D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" is a hint that Postgres wants to talk to the SystemD daemon. I am running Postgres in a centos-7 docker container by using the https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement to avoid that situation.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is explained and can be resolved with this answer:

[Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/824975/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted)

You make your own new image (`centos7-systemd`) but it isn't as hard as it looks.  But be careful to do exactly what it says, running your new image via:

`docker run --privileged  -ti -e container=docker  -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup  centos7-systemd /usr/sbin/init`

and then connect to it via e.g.

`$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6667f8acbe5c        centos7-systemd       "/usr/sbin/init"    33 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes                           eager_brattain
$ docker exec -it eager_brattain bash`

Then run those postgres instructions at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation and they will work fine.